# What's the minimum number of operations needed to copy a string n times?

Tags: algorithm

Recently, I had to duplicate a string a specified number of times. Let's say that I had to have 5 copies of a string "`bacon`", and that I had 1 line of "`bacon`" in my editor. So I would start with this:

```
bacon
```

And end with this:

```
bacon
bacon
bacon
bacon
bacon
```

Let's also define three "atomic" operations: copy, paste, and delete. 'Copy' allows you to copy **any** number of lines, 'paste' pastes whatever has been most recently copied, and 'delete' deletes a line. So if I have 3 lines of "`bacon`":

```
bacon
bacon
bacon
```

And I want 10 lines of "`bacon`," I could do something like this:

```
copy 2  | lines of bacon: 3
paste 2 | lines of bacon: 5
copy 5  | lines of bacon: 5
paste 5 | lines of bacon: 10
```

But what's the minimum number of "atomic" operations necessary given *i* lines and *j* desired lines, with *i* ≤ *j*? Is there an algorithmic technique that applies to this problem? Or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: I'd ignore the fact that you have lines of text involved at all, and look only at the numbers, and how to progress from one number to another by adding any number up to the original number to itself. It seems to me the math works out to something on the same general order as figuring the steps for a Booth multiplier.

Comment: I think this is a mathematical puzzle rather than a programming question.  (The programming answer is "who cares" ... and then write a simple `for` loop.)

Comment: @StephenC, I've had to solve this puzzle when copying lines of source in an editor.

Comment: @MarkRansom - no you haven't ... or at least you only did if you used a lame editor that didn't provide a simple way to repeat an edit operation N-times.

Comment: @StephenC, it was either a lame editor or a lame operator. I spend 99% of my time in Visual C++ so draw your own conclusions. I can't remember enough to know why I thought copy/paste was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a sequence delete followed by paste.  Note that this yields the same state as paste followed by delete.  So these operations can be swapped back and forth.

Next consider a sequence delete followed by "copy N".  Note that this ends up in the same state as "copy N" followed by delete, so these sequences can be swapped (but only in one direction).

Therefore, in any sequence of operations, we can swap any delete with the operation following it without changing the final result.  Therefore, we can move all of the delete operations to the end without changing the result.

From this it follows that if any deletes appear in the optimal sequence, they can be moved to the end of the sequence:

```
XXXXXXXXDDDD
```

(Where X is either C or P)

But it cannot be optimal to have a copy without a subsequent paste, so the sequence actually looks like:

```
XXXXXXPDDDD
```

Now, observe that any paste + delete (PD) sequence can be replaced by a copy + paste (CP) sequence, where the copy just grabs one fewer lines.  This replaces two operations with two other operations, so it loses nothing.  So we can transform our optimal sequence into:

```
XXXXXXCPDDD
```

And we can do it again three times to eliminate all of the deletes:

```
XXXXXXCCCCP
```

Of course, a sequence of copies is sub-optimal, so our answer must look like:

```
XXXXXXCP
```

In other words, deletes are never required as part of the optimal sequence.

Four pastes in a row are never required, because they can always be replaced by copy + paste + copy + paste.  (Three pastes in a row can be required, though; e.g. to get from 4 to 13)

And that's as far as I get for now.  At this point I might just do a Dijkstra-style breadth-first search for the shortest path...

[update]

As Mark Peters points out in a comment, three pastes in a row is never needed, either.  Proof:

Copy(N) requires that N be less than the number of lines.  So Copy(N) + Paste + Paste + Paste can always be replaced by Copy(N) + Paste + Copy(2N) + Paste.

So an optimal sequence can be formed with no deletes, no two copies in a row, and no more than two pastes in a row.  Well, it's a start.

Comment: 4 to 13: C3-P-C6-P vs C3-P-P-P.  I don't think you need three pastes in a row.

Comment: Seems like `copy all` `paste all` doubles the size, and for the last copy-paste sequence we can simply copy-paste whatever is left.  That is `2*log2(N)` operations  (I haven't worked out how the rounding has to work though, or if there has to be a `+1` or `-1` somewhere)

Comment: @MooingDuck:  I do not think such a simple approach works if you want the absolute minimum.  For example, to get from 4 to 10, the correct sequence is C(3) P P.  Doubling first would yield C(4) P C(2) P, which is one more operation than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Two operations, copy + paste, can double the number of lines at a maximum. The ratio of operations to size is 2:2. If you do it twice in a row you get 4x for 4 operations.

Three operations, copy + paste + paste, can triple the number of lines at a maximum. The ratio of operations to lines is 3:3, or the same as the previous. But if you do it twice in a row you get 9x for 6 operations, which is an improvement.

Four operations, copy + paste + paste + paste, can quadruple the number of lines. Again the ratio is the same at 4:4. If you do it twice in a row you get 16x for 8 operations.

Five operations, copy + 4*paste, can multiply the number of lines by 5. But combining the two and three operations sequences can multiply the number of lines by 6 for the same number of operations. If you extrapolate these out you can see that there's no way to beat the combinations of the 2, 3, and 4 operation sequences.

My advice would be to use the 4 operation sequence until the result is within 4x of the target, then switch to the 3 or 2 operation sequence to finish.

Comment: This will be close to optimal, but not necessarily exact...  Consider getting from 4 to 29.  Your algorithm would do CPPP (to get to 16), then CP to finish, for a total of six operations.  But the right answer is CP (to get to 8), copy 7, then PPP, for a total of five operations.  I suspect there are many similar examples where the precise state in the copy buffer can save you a step at various points along the way, although I do not have my head around it yet.

Comment: @Nemo I don't doubt that you're right and there are cases where you can do one better than my algorithm. You miscounted on your example though, you have 6 total operations.

Comment: OK, so make it 4 to 22 (C4, P, C7, PP).  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's canonicalize the sequence we're looking for. This starts out like Nemo's answer.

1. Valid sequences are matched by D*(C[DP]*)*. Rewrite D C(n) → C(n) D and D P(n) → P(n) D.
2. Valid sequences are matched by (CP*)*D*. Rewrite C(n) D → D and P(n) D → C(n-1) P(n-1). The new copy is OK because the buffer length as a function of time is unimodal.
3. Valid sequences are matched by (CP*)*|D*.

Since i ≤ j, the sequence we're looking for matches (CP*)*.

1. Valid sequences are matched by (CP*)*. Rewrite C(n) P(n) P(n) P(n) P(n) P(n) → C(n) P(n) C(2n) P(2n) P(2n) C(n).
2. Valid sequences are matched by (CP{0,4})*. Rewrite C(n) C(n') → C(n').
3. Valid sequences are matched by (CP{1,4})*. Rewrite C(n) P(n) P(n) P(n) P(n) → C(n) P(n) P(n) C(2n) P(2n). We don't need to restore the copy because the next command, if it exists, is a copy.
4. Valid sequences are matched by (CP{1,3})*. Rewrite C(n) P(n) P(n) P(n) → C(n) P(n) C(2n) P(2n). We don't need to restore the copy.

The sequence we're looking for matches (CP{1,2})*. Abbreviate 2(n) = C(n) P(n) and 3(n) = C(n) P(n) P(n). Call a copy *whole* if it copies the whole buffer and *partial* if not. Call a copy *almost whole* if it copies the whole buffer except for one line. I'll use w and p and a to annotate commands.

Let's work on reducing the number of partial copies. Suppose we have 2p(n) … 2?(n'). We can rewrite to 2w(n+δ) … 2p(n'-δ) or 2w(n+n') … , decreasing the number of partial copies. We can do the same for 3p(n) … 3?(n'). Assuming optimality, we can do 3p(n) … 2?(n'). We can't get stuck with 3p(n+δ) … 2p(1) because 3?(n+δ+1) … D is equivalent and shorter. We can sort of do 2p(n) … 3?(n'), but the 2 may be only almost whole in the end.

This rewriting converges if we always work on the leftmost partial copy with a mate. After further rewriting 2w(n) 3w(2n) → 3w(n) 2w(3n) and 2w(n) 2w(2n) 2w(4n) 2w(8n) → 2w(n) 3w(2n) 3p(5n), valid sequences are matched by 2w{0,3} 3w* ( | 2p | 2a? 3w* 3p ).

### log(n)-time algorithm

Clearly the optimal solution is of length O(log(n)). We can compute lower and upper bounds on the number of 3w commands in each solution that matches the regular expression above; these bounds differ by a uniform constant. Try *all* plausible short sequences of commands, of which there are O(log(n)). At most one copy amount is unspecified; it is easy enough to compute what it should be if the pattern works.